# WPBakery Visual Composer Text Block issue

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I am facing an issue with my visual composer, I can add a text block edit, and save, and when I back to change again the text, the visual composer back to its default text block.
How to solve that.
WPBakery Visual Composer 4.12
attached is the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQAxE.png)

Comment: Maybe you running an outdated version of Visual Composer? your Version is from 2016.

Comment: Start using a new version of Visual composer. Avoid if you can Visual composer.